# Dynamically add form and button that uses the properties of form in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a form dynamically and than add a new button to form(also dynamically).
now I want to write code on button click event , how I can use form properties. (It generates scope issue. ), should I declare my form as public...?   [code of program
][1]

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Form myform = new Form();
        myform.Show();
        myform.Text = "New Dynamic Window";
        Button hide = new Button();
        hide.Text = "Hide";
        hide.Show();
        hide.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        hide.Click += hide_Click;
        myform.Controls.Add(hide);
    }

    void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                   // myform.Hide();

    }
```

when I write `myform.Hide();` in 
my click event of button it generates error.

Comment: coul you please post your code ?  instead of image.

Comment: I write code  kindly check...

Comment: YOu have to declare myForm outsite the button3_click event

Answer (score 2):

You are creating your myForm in your click event. The variable has method level scope. Try declaring it as a class scoped variable and new it up in your click event.

```
 Form myform; //Notice that I have removed your declaration from your click event
              //this variable now has visibility throughout the entire class.

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myForm = new Form();  // I have instantiated it here
    myform.Show();
    myform.Text = "New Dynamic Window";
    Button hide = new Button();
    hide.Text = "Hide";
    hide.Show();
    hide.Location = new Point(50, 50);
    hide.Click += hide_Click;
    myform.Controls.Add(hide);
}

void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

               // myform.Hide();

}
```

Or You can leave it the way you have it and cast the sender object in your hide_Click event to a Button since it is the object the originated the event and its parent is the Form you can then cast it to Form then call its Hide method.

```
void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Form)((Button)sender).Parent).Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In  your event handler you have access to the `sender` parameter. You can use this parameter to access the parent form. Here is the sample code:

```
  void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         ((sender as Button).Parent as Form).Hide();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
void hide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((Control)sender).FindForm().Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is not accessible in Button click . 
you should declare your form as a class member.